# Delete operation takes some time to accomplish

Tags: sql, database, performance

I have a method to delete records in a DB, the query is created correctly and the records are deleted but after 40 seconds to 1 minute

If i execute the query in the DB prompt the record is deleted immediately

The code i have is only :

- getting the database connection
- preparing the statement passing 3 variables to the "delete from" sentence
- calling executeUpdate on the statement
- calling commit on the connection
- closing the db connection

What could it be wrong? any clue?

Comment: The more information you provide, the better answers we can give.  What is the DBMS? What language are you working in, and specifically what is the source code for your delete routine?

Comment: Are you suggesting the the produced SQL statement as a whole takes milliseconds in the prompt? Or that deleting a single row takes milliseconds in the prompt?

Comment: @user695907 - What do you mean by "commit on the connection". Are you executing a single statement (and therefore do not need a transaction)? How many rows are in the table in question? Is anything else querying the table while you are trying to delete the rows (thus preventing the acquisition of an update lock).

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly assuming that a DELETE statement is very trivial in all cases, which is not always true. At very least, it needs to find the records it want to remove in the table. This may require an entire table scan if, for example, the WHERE predicate cannot leverage an existing index.

Comment: well, during testing i have only 1 record in the DB, and even though it takes some time to complete   =|

Comment: @user then I would run the debugger, step through your code and see which line is slowing execution.

Comment: @user If everything else is fine, there might be another transaction holding an exclusive lock on the table for a long time...